# Serializing child class if parent class does not implement serializable?

Tags: java, serialization

```
public class Employee2 extends Employee1 {} 

public class Employee1  extends Employee0 {}

public class Employee0  {}
```

Now i serialize the Employee2 class  and

```
get the error  java.io.NotSerializableException: Employee2
```

Now if changed  Employee1 class def to

```
public class Employee1  extends Employee0 implements java.io.Serializable {}
```

it works fine but please note Employee0 still does not implement Serializable

Is it mandatory for Base class has to implement Serializable to serialize the child class? If yes why its mandatory only for Employee1  but not for Employee0 ?

As per my example it looks like yes but as per other articles on net this should not be mandatory. So what i am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to serialize an `Employee2` object, `Employee2` has to implement `Serializable` (preferably directly rather than inheriting it). You weren't getting the exception because `Employee1` isn't serializable, you were getting it because `Employee2` isn't, and you tried to serialize it anyway.

`Employee1` and `Employee0` don't necessarily have to implement `Serializable`, but if they don't, they have to have no-argument constructors (so that the serializer can instantiate the reconstructed `Employee2` object).