# Deserializing the serialized object

Tags: java

If Base class doesn't implement Serializable Interface but Derived class implements Serializable interface, will I be able to deserialiaze the serialized object? Because when I tried to do it, I got ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFound means that the required .class file does **not** exist in the context of the JVM where you try to de-serialize (so that is a classpath setup problem!)

And then: this will **only** work if all superclasses that are not Serializiable contain a no-argument default constructor (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475713/serializing-child-class-if-parent-class-does-not-implement-serializable) for further information).

Comment: You are welcome. And just to be sure you don't miss that - you can accept  one (and after reaching upvote level) also upvote one or more of the answers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You won't be able to deserialize because your member variable is of reference type and if it does not implement serializable then the value for the reference variable will be null in the stream after serialization. So, while deserializing , Java internally call **Class.forname()** to get that reference variable back into object. Since it was null , you will get ClassNotFoundException .

Soltn.. :-
Make the reference variable class to implement serializable